# string в массив int c++

Tags: c++, массивы

Уважаемые программисты! Возник такой вопрос: как перевести string, допустим "1244 22 12 56 7" в динамический массив int, чтобы он содержал {1244, 22, 12, 56, 7}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть много-много способов. Но все сводятся к разделению и потом переводу в числа.

вот один с любимых и простых

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<int> parse(const std::string& s) {
    std::vector<int> r;
    std::stringstream ss{s};
    int n;
    while (ss >> n) { r.push_back(n);}
    return r;
}

int main(){
    std::string s = "1244 22 12 56 7";
    std::vector<int> r = parse(s);
    for (auto el : r) {
        std::cout << el << "\n";
    }
}
```

А вот пример, как можно сделать эту же функцию, но "без внешних зависимостей". Правда она очень требовательная к формату - шаг в сторону и она работает неверно

```
std::vector<int> parse(const std::string& s) {
    std::vector<int> r;
    int n = 0;
    for (char c : s) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            r.push_back(n);
            n = 0;
        } else {
            n = n*10+c-'0';
        }
    }
    r.push_back(n);
    return r;
}
```

P.S. Многие, когда пишут "динамический массив" хотят почему то видеть указатель, но у нас же с++, а здесь динамический массив - это std::vector.

Comment: А не могли бы вы немного пояснить что происходит :)

Comment: а что именно не понятно?

Comment: Я так понимаю в первом отрывке кода "parse" это название функции? А почему тогда оно в одной строчке с объявлением вектора и зачем вообще его объявлять там если мы объявили его ниже "r". Или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: первый отрывок кода не есть отрывком. Это полностью готовая программа, которая содержит функцию parse, которая собственно делает Вашу задачу. В строке `std::vector<int> parse(const std::string& s)` начало - `std::vector<int>` - это возвращаемый тип. Насколько хорошо Вы знаете базовый с++?

Comment: Знаю плохо)....

Comment: то есть возвращаемый тип у нас вектор потому что функция возвращает готовый вектор, так?

Comment: если бы функция была бы `int parse(int data)`, то  здесь есть проблемы с пониманием? а тут ровно тоже самое, просто тип чуточку посложнее.

Comment: Да да, понял, спасибо. А что такое   ''''std::stringstream ss{s};'''

Comment: std::stringstream - это такой класс, который позволяет завернуть обычную строку в что то, похожее на std::cin и как будто вводить с него. Собственно  `ss` - это имя объекта этого типа, а s - это исходная строка, которая передается как параметр.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: А не могли бы вы еще объяснить что такое push_back и auto)))

Comment: auto - это фича с++11 и старше, которая говорит дословно "компилятор, ты же и так понимаешь, какой там будет тип, выведи пожалуйста его сам". Хотя в примере выше можно было и просто int написать, будет даже короче. push_back - добавить в массив (вектор) в самый конец.